# Architecture for the project

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I have done a windows project in which I have a simple download button which downloads contents from an external web portal. Here I have done with dataaccess class which is used for CRUD operations. Now I need to seperate UI and business logic layer. My UI code looks a bit untidy. So I need to create a BLL. For BLL, can I write the html parsing method (ProcessHtml) and the method which uses httpwebrequest to get html output of webpage(SendHTTPRequest) and the method which uses the html contents to write into a doc file.(WriteToFile). Will it make sense?.Simply
Can I use in BLL the below methods.

```
    BLL  
  ProcessHtml()
SendHTTPRequest()
WriteToFile()
```

Comment: There should not be any HTML in your business logic...

Comment: So you are telling the method which I used to process html using htmlagility pack should be in UI code itself.right?

Comment: Î would introduce another layer called DataAccess

Comment: I have done with dataacess which is used for CRUD operations. Still my UI contains alot of code.So thats why I am thinking about designing a BLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundaries of the layers here are too thin, and it depends on how you would like to code you project.

What **I** would do, in this case, is introduce some: *BridgeLayer*, which transforms UI data, to the format suitable for storing/retriving informaiton from some store. In that layer I would push `HtmlAgilityPack`.

If you're familiar with `MVVM` design, in other words it would be `ModelView` layer: something that knows how to make talk UI with data, considering that the *format* of them could be completely different.

Comment: Ok. So what about the other functions, like sending a request to the webpage(SendHTTPRequest) and WriteTOFile( Used to write html into word). May I know your suggestion?

Comment: @sachin: It depeds: Sending request, would leave in ModelView, in this case who sends request can trasform data from datamodel to the format UI understans. What about FileWriting, I don't knwo *what* and *when* you gonna write into the file. Base on conditions it could be in datamodel and in modelview as well.